# intercept DOM elements on click in a .NET WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, html, dom, browser

With a `WebBrowser` control, is it possible intercept the element (input text, input button, textarea, table...) when the user clicks over?

I load an HTML page in the WebBrowser control, the user clicks over an element (for example, an input text), and I intercept that the user has clicked that element, so I can get the attributes of the clicked element.

Is this possible, if so how?

Comment: Take a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312777 - it is a KB detailing how to handle events from the WebBrowser control